# Command line subset sum

Tags: c, arrays, command-line, subset

I'm making a program that takes a target value and a set list of values, I need to pick numbers from the list that will add up to the target value.

This all has to be done on the command line.

Im stuck on two parts:

First is I'm not 100% sure if I'm reading in all the values correctly. Because on some tests where there shouldn't be a match it says there is a match.

For example
subset2 100 1 2 3 4
Combination Match Found

It should print out instead no match found cause 1,2,3,4 dont add up to 100.
I've added my code to help you see what im doing

Second, 
I need to print out the numbers in the list that do match with the target value. How would I be able to do that, I'm stumped on how i could do this.

For example
subset 9 1 2 4 5
{4,5}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool subset(int set[], int n, int sum);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Error checking to see if the value is a negative
    if (value <= 0) {
        printf("Parameter 1 can not be negative\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int k;
    int t = 0;

    for (k = 2; k < argc; k++) {
        t++;
    }

    int i;
    int array = 0;

    /*
     * Putting the elements from the command line in an array starting
     * from the second element on the command line
     */

    for (i = 2; i < t; i++) {
        array += atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    int set[array];
    int n = sizeof(set) / sizeof(set[0]);

    // Call subset to check and see if there is a match
    if (subset(set, n, value) == true) {
        printf("Combination Match Found\n");
    } else {
        printf("No Combination Matches\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

// Returns true if there is a subset that equals the value
bool subset(int set[], int n, int sum)
{
    // Base cases
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;

    if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
        return false;

    // If last element is greater than sum, then its ignored
    if (set[n - 1] > sum)
        return (subset, n - 1, sum);

    // Check if value can be found with or without last element
    return subset(set, n - 1, sum) || subset(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't know `c# != C`

Comment: You never initialize `set[i]` to values from command line. In fact, they are all left uninitialized, which causes weird results to show up. Also `n` is incorrect (it is the sum of values after second parameter - but not all of them). You may want to double check/rewrite the part where you read the data from parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're kind of all over the place. I'll address a few minor issues first.

```
int value = atoi(argv[1]);
```

will crash if you didn't put any arguments on the command line. You should check `argc > 1` first.

```
for (k = 2; k < argc; k++) {
    t++;
}
```

Could have been written

```
t = argc - 2;
```

As for initializing **set[]**:

```
for (i = 2; i < t; i++) {
    array += atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Should have been

```
for (i=0; i<t; ++i) {
    set[i] = atoi(argv[i+2]));
}
```

**set[]** is your array of inputs, right? It's length should be the number of arguments from the command line, right? If I'm reading that right, then the size of **set** should be **t**, not **array**. In fact, I don't see you using **t** anywhere after you've computed it. **array** is the sum of the input values; is that even useful to you (other than as a preliminary check to see if the problem is solvable)?

If you want to actually print out your results rather than test to see if it's possible, then you're going to have to allocate an array for the results, and make some significant changes to **subset()**.

I would create another array, named **result[]** with the same length as **set[]**. I would pass a pointer to **result[]** to **subset()**, along with a count of how many values have already been filled in (initial value 0). In **subset()**, any time you have a value from **set[]** that's a possible legal value, append it to **result[]** and increment the length. Likewise, decrement the length before returning from **subset()**, effectively removing your intermediate value. Once **subset()** has determined that there's a legal combination of values that sum up to your target, that list of values has been placed in **result[]**.

Is this a homework assignment? If so, I'm loathe to write any actual code for you, but I hope my description above helps.

Finally -- and this is a little advanced -- you might want to do a little research into [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) as optimizations of this kind of problem.

Comment: Mmkay i see what your saying. i needed an outside perspective on my program cause i knew parts of it were messed up couldn't think of what i missed. This is just something im doing to keep my programming skills up to date. I mess up quite a bit thats why i like having outside perspectives to help me catch stuff i missed. What you have said has helped me see where my errors are i will go and correct myself and see where it leads me  thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool subset(int set[], int n, int sum);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int value = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (value <= 0) {
        printf("Parameter 1 must be positive\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int array_size = argc - 2;
    int set[array_size];
    for(int i=0;i<array_size;++i)
        set[i] = atoi(argv[2 + i]);

    // Call subset to check and see if there is a match
    if (subset(set, array_size, value) == true) {
        printf("Combination Match Found\n");
    } else {
        printf("No Combination Matches\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

// Returns true if there is a subset that equals the value
bool subset(int set[], int n, int target_sum){
    if (target_sum == 0){
        printf("{ }\n");
        return true;
    }
    if (n == 0 && target_sum != 0)
        return false;

    unsigned limit = 1 << n;
    int wk[n];
    for(unsigned i=1;i < limit; ++i){
        int k = 0, sum = 0;
        unsigned x = i;
        for(int j = 0; x ; ++j, x>>=1){
            if(x & 1){
                sum += (wk[k++] = set[j]);
                if(sum  > target_sum) break;
            }
        }
        if(sum == target_sum){
            printf("{ ");
            for(int j = 0;j<k;++j)
                printf("%d ", wk[j]);
            printf("}\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```